# Update ProfilePicture in chat without flicker XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am currently working on a user to user chat on my website. I need help with a problem regarding the retrieving of img data from my database to optimize it. To briefly summarize how the chat works is as following.

I use a "One to n" database structure for the messages.

messages(table) -> |id|uid|msg|chatroomid|

The chatrooms table looks as following

chatrooms(table) -> |id|user1|user2|

$chatroomId is a variable to display the current clicked chat

I display the chats in the following way.

logs.php

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['chatRoomId'])) {
  $chatroomId = $_SESSION['chatRoomId'];
} else {
  $chatroomId = 0; //There will be no such and we use 0 for the else later
}
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$result1 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE chatroomId = $chatroomId ORDER BY id");

$getIds = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM chatrooms WHERE id = $chatroomId");

$getIdsResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getIds);
$user1 = $getIdsResult['user1'];
$user2 = $getIdsResult['user2'];

$selfId = 0;
$guestId = 0;

if($user1 == $id){
  $selfId = $user1;
  $guestId = $user2;
} else {
  $selfId = $user2;
  $guestId = $user1;
}


echo "<div class = 'chat-logs'>";

//If possible if we wouldnt have to get all of the images EVERY TIME
if(isset($_SESSION['chatRoomId'])){
  while ($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    $from = $extract['from'];
    if($from == $id){
      echo "
       <div class = 'chat self'>
         <div class = 'imageContainer'>
           <img src = 'displayProfilePicture.php?user_id=$selfId'>
         </div>
         <div class = 'chat-message'>
           ".$extract['msg']."
         </div>
       </div>";
     } else {
        echo "
          <div class = 'chat friend'>
            <div class = 'imageContainer'>
              <img src = 'displayProfilePicture.php?user_id=$guestId'>
            </div>
            <div class = 'chat-message'>
              ".$extract['msg']."
            </div>
          </div>";
     }
  } 
} else {
  echo "No messages";//To be continued...
}
```

I use a XMLHttpRequest to call the script every 200:th millisecond with the help of jQuery and load the response into the chatlogs div.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
setInterval(function(){ 
  $( "#chatlogs" ).load( "logs.php", function() { 
      //Something to be executed after the logs is loaded if we want
    });
  }, 200);
});
```

It is currently working all good. The chat works and is updated correctly as i want it to. Except for one thing. If we look back at how i load the images who are stored as "blobs" in the database i display them with another php script "displayProfilePicture.php?user_id=n". What this is causing is that it makes for a flicker as the logs.php is loaded and it constantly updates the img as it calls the profilePicture.php.

From browsing the web having a separate script for displaying blobs seems to be the correct way of doing it. So ultimatly what my question is if there is some way for me to just load the image once and then reuse it as variable or something every time i call the logs.php? I hope i have provided enough information and stated the problem in a understandable way if not please do let me know how i can add more information of value so that we together can find a solution.

Best regards

Comment: You need to cache the profile pictures by setting the appropriate headers in the response. That way they won't reload every time.

Comment: When you say cache the profile pictures. What do you mean by defintion with that. Do you have a link where i can find out more about this?

Comment: Have a look here: https://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/

Comment: So i went ahed and read a little bit about the tip you gave me and i found a few ppl pointing to this

"If you are using php to check if the user is logged in before outputting the message, then you don't want the browser to cache the image..
The entire point of caching is to call the server once and then never call it again. If the browser caches the image, it won't call the server and your script won't run. Instead, the browser will pull your image from cache and display it, even if the user is no longer logged in. This could potentially be a very big security hole."

Is it a breach?

Comment: You can add an expiration date to the headers, so the browser won't cache the image until infinity and beyond. And since you're "only" dealing with profile pictures and not with sensitive data like a users email address, I would not consider it a security breach.